# Default Address in Web Request: sendRedirect: Absolute vs Relative Path

Tags: java, web, jboss

I have an EAR file and its application.xml is something like

```
<web-uri>pharma.war</web-uri>
<context-root>pharma</context-root>
```

When I start the application, I use below URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/pharma/Login
```

Login is a servlet defined in WEB-INF of war file. In the servlet, I am saying it to redirect to app/launchPage.html. It is supposed to redirect to

`http://localhost:8080/pharma/app/launchPage.html` but it is redirecting to

```
http://localhost:8080/app/launchPage.html.
```

Same thing is working in JBoss EAP 4.2. I am trying to migrate to JBoss EAP 6.3.0. I think, I missed some configuration but not sure what configuration.

```
ServletRootPath="/Login"
redirectPagePath="app/launchPage.html"

Java Code: ctx.getResponse().sendRedirect(redirectPagePath);
ctx.getResponse() returns an object of type HttpServletResponse
```

Can you please let me know, what I am missing here

Comment: you are missing `request.getContextPath` in redirect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724565/is-using-request-getcontextpath-in-scriptlet-for-jsp-is-a-good-practise

Comment: Since I am passing a relative path, should it not prepend the contextpath on its own?