# The requested resource is not available - Java, Servlet/Controller

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hello guys i been stuck on this for a few hours no idea what i am missing here... 
I got a few simple pages, one of them is for registering a new user. 
I am using Eclipse with a servlet as a controller (MVC).

register.jsp  Page

```
            <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <title>register page</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                  <form action="RegisterController" method="post">
                        <center>
                            <table border="1" width="15%" cellpadding="5">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="2">Register Form</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                    <tr>    
                                        <td>Username</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="userName" value=""></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Password</td>
                                        <td><input type="password" name="password" value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><center><input type="submit" value="Register"></center></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>             
                            </table>
                        </center>
                    </form>
            </body>
            </html>


            /*registerController page*/
            package com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project.Controller;

            import java.io.IOException;

            import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
            import javax.servlet.ServletException;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

            import com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project.Model.ToDoListPlatformException;
            import com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project.Model.ToDoListService;
            import com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project.Model.ToDoListUser;

            /**
             * Servlet implementation class RegisterController
             */

            public class RegisterController extends HttpServlet {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


                protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
                    String password = request.getParameter("password");
                    ToDoListUser toDoListUser = new ToDoListUser(1,userName,password);
                    ToDoListService toDoListService = new ToDoListService();

                    try 
                    {
                        toDoListService.addUser(toDoListUser);
                        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
                        rd.forward(request,response);
                    }
                    catch (ToDoListPlatformException e) 
                    {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <display-name>LoginController</display-name>
        <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project.controller.LoginController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>RegisterController</display-name>
        <servlet-name>RegisterController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project.controller.RegisterController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>ToDoListAddController</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ToDoListAddController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project.controller.ToDoListAddController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>ToDoListDeleteController</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ToDoListDeleteController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project.controller.ToDoListDeleteController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>ToDoListUpdateController</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ToDoListUpdateController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project.controller.ToDoListUpdateController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RegisterController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/RegisterController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ToDoListAddController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ToDoListAddController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ToDoListDeleteController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ToDoListDeleteController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ToDoListUpdateController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ToDoListUpdateController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

No matter what i do i keep getting the 404 resource is not available error when i press on the submit button.
This is the error i am getting :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project/servlet/com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project.Controller.RegisterController
type Status report
message /com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project/servlet/com.IvgeniKravtsov.Project.Controller.RegisterController
description The requested resource is not available.
```

The JSP pages located at the WebContent folder.
Any help or a direction to what i am doing wrong will be very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: edit the question with web.xml

Comment: Can you replace action attribute declared under form tag in register.jsp to ... /<url-pattern> attribute declared for the servlet in Web.xml?

Comment: I just added the Web.xml file guys

Answer (score 0):

You try it please.

```
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/RegisterController" method="post">
...
```

> request.getContextPath()- return root path of your application, while  ../ - returns parent directory of a file.

See also:

[How is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724565/how-is-using-request-getcontextpath-better-than)

Comment: sadly it didnt help, i think i will try to start a new project from scratch and copy some code to new files etc... i got a feeling that maybe i messed up the project itself at some point of my work.